# C#: divide an int by 100

Tags: c#, divide

How do I divide an `int` by 100?

eg:

```
int x = 32894;
int y = 32894 / 100;
```

Why does this result in `y` being `328` and not `328.94`?

Comment: You're doing integer divisions which are magically rounded. Try (32894.0/100.0). On a totally relevant node, how do you expect to store 328.94 in an integer data type?

Comment: @Ravi if the expected answer is 328.94, then ***do not*** use `double`...

Comment: @Marc: why can't `double` be used?

Comment: @Craig: The number 328.94 can't be represented exactly as a double. see the links at the end of my answer. The closest exact double is 328.93999999999999772626324556767940521240234375.

Comment: @Craig because floating point arithmetic (IEEE754) won't necessarily give you what you expect, due to how the numbers are represented/rounded. `decimal` uses base-10 arithmetic/rounding, which will preserve your crisp `.94`.

Comment: @Marc @Jon: That was a great point. Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When one integer is divided by another, the arithmetic is performed *as* integer arithmetic.

If you want it to be performed as float, double or decimal arithmetic, you need to cast one of the values appropriately. For example:

```
decimal y = ((decimal) x) / 100;
```

Note that I've changed the type of `y` as well - it doesn't make sense to perform decimal arithmetic but then store the result in an `int`. The `int` can't possibly store 328.94.

You only need to force *one* of the values to the right type, as then the other will be promoted to the same type - there's no operator defined for dividing a decimal by an integer, for example. If you're performing arithmetic using several values, you might want to force *all* of them to the desired type just for clarity - it would be unfortunate for one operation to be performed using integer arithmetic, and another using double arithmetic, when you'd expected both to be in double.

If you're using literals, you can just use a suffix to indicate the type instead:

```
decimal a = x / 100m; // Use decimal arithmetic due to the "m"
double b = x / 100.0; // Use double arithmetic due to the ".0"
double c = x / 100d; // Use double arithmetic due to the "d"
double d = x / 100f; // Use float arithmetic due to the "f"
```

As for whether you should be using `decimal`, `double` or `float`, that depends on what you're trying to do. Read my articles on [decimal floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) and [binary floating point](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx). Usually `double` is appropriate if you're dealing with "natural" quantities such as height and weight, where *any* value will really be an approximation; `decimal` is appropriate with artificial quantities such as money, which are typically represented exactly *as decimal values* to start with.

Comment: This will not compile. You are trying to assign a decimal to an int.

Comment: Didn't see it. Good to see it fixed. Gave +1 since after your edits, this is clearly the best answer :)

Comment: @Øyvind: It was a fair complaint, certainly - I was embarrassed when I noticed I'd initially posted the uncompilable code :)

Comment: Yet again Mr. Skeet to the rescue.

Answer (score 3):

Because an int is only a whole number. Try this instead.

```
int x = 32894;
double y = x / 100.0;
```

Comment: With `double` arithmetic there is **still** no guarantee of getting `328.94`

Comment: That is true. So assure an exact figure, he should probably use decimal instead, but in many cases I assume that double precision will be enough.

Answer (score 3):

328.94 is not an integer. Integer `/` divide rounds down; that is how it works.

I suggest you cast to decimal:

```
decimal y = 32894M / 100;
```

or with variables:

```
decimal y = (decimal)x / 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're doing integer division. Add a period behind the 100 and you'll get a double instead.

When you divide two integers, the result is an integer. Integers don't have decimal places, so they're just truncated.

Answer (score 0):

its programming fundamental that int(integer) dividing is different from float(floating point) dividing.

if u want .94 use float or double

```
var num = 3294F/100F
```